# Overriding serializers __init__ method to create nested serializers with custom parameters

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have created basic serializer in Django Rest Framework for model containing an ImageField.

```
# images/models.py

from django.db import models


def upload_to(instance, filename):
    """Generate file path for the new image""":
    return 'changeit'


class Image(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to)
    user = models.ForeignKey('users.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```
# images/serializers.py

"""
Serializers for uploading images.
"""

import os

from rest_framework import serializers

from images.models import Image
from images.utils import resize_image


class ImageSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """Serializer for Image model."""

    def __init__(self, instance=None, height=None, **kwargs):
        """Add height parameter to serializer contructor."""
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.height = height

    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    img = serializers.ImageField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Assign uploaded image to authenticated user."""
        return resize_image(
            user=self.context['request'].user,
            height=self.height,
            image=validated_data['img']
        )

    def validate_img(self, value):
        """Validate file extension."""
        _, extension = os.path.splitext(value._get_name())
        if extension not in ('.jpg', '.png'):
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Invalid file extension.')
        return value


class BasicTierUserSerializer(ImageSerializer):
    """Serializer for Basic tier user."""
    
    thumbnail_200px = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    def get_thumbnail_200px(self, obj):
        return ImageSerializer(obj, height=200).data
```

```
# images/utils.py

"""
Utility functions for manipulating uploaded images.
"""

from PIL import Image

from config import celery_app
from images.models import Image


@celery_app.task(bind=True)
def resize_image(self, user, image, height):
    if not height:
        return Image.objects.create(
            user=user,
            img=image,
        )
    new_height = height
    new_width = int(image.width * (new_height / image.height))
    return Image.objects.create(
        user=user,
        img=image.resize((new_height, new_width)),
    )
```

I want to return response based on authenticated user tier. For example, for Basic user I want to return an URL to 200px thumbnail, for Premium user I want to return URLs to 200px thumbnail and 400px thumbnail. I decided to create some nested serializers, since I wanted to reuse inherited create method. To modify behaviour of create method based on arguments passed to serializer I have overwritten the serializer's special **init** method.

However when I am posting new image on the endpoint, it returns URL to inherited 'img' field as expected, but the 'thumbnail_200px' is always equal to {'img': None}. For example:
{
'id': 2,
'img': 'http://testserver/static/media/changeit/tmpvlpl0x0o_kY7iBu5.png',
'thumbnail_200px': {'img': None}
}

Could you help me spot the problem or give me a hint how to do it in more reliable way?